# Rails/Active Record, Order by association / has_many count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a collection of books and they can have many topics associated through another table.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_topics, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :topics, through: :book_topics
end
```

Then I have a helper to list out all the topics, but I want to list topics to be ordered by the number of books that have that topic.

I've tried variations of:

```
def topic_list
  Topic.joins(:book_topics)
       .group("book_topics.topic_id")
       .order("count(book_topics.book_id) desc")
end
```

With no luck.

Comment: `book_topics.video_id`? Is that field even in `book_topics` table? I would expect to see `topic_id`. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, meant that to be topic_id, not video_id - not the problem, just bad typing on my behalf.

Comment: Fix that in your question then. And it seems legit to me, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I get 

`ERROR:  column "topics.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`



`SELECT "topics".* FROM "topics" INNER JOIN "book_topics" ON "book_topics"."topic_id" = "topics"."id" GROUP BY book_topics.topic_id  ORDER BY count(book_topics.book_id) desc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think that proper way to do this would be to implement [counter cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

in book_topic.rb you would have

```
class BookTopic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic, counter_cache: true
end
```

topic.rb should stay the same

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_topics, dependent: :destroy
end
```

however, you would have to add the counter column to the topics table

```
class AddBookTopicsCountToTopics < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :topics, :book_topics_count, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

migrate it, update counter val if you have existing records, and from there it should be easy to sort topics by the number of books they have.

i realize you want a query to solve this, but in my experience this should be much faster.

sry if there are mistakes. counter name is not the best, but there's an example in the docs how to change it. if it's not enough there's also a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) vid.